# How to obliterate/modify changelists in particular Perforce/Helix workspace

Tags: perforce

Due to legal issues, we had to obliterate entire projects from our Helix/Perforce repositories.

We were partially successful, all the past versions of the files are gone, the depots are gone too.

However, the workspaces and all the associated changelists are still there (P4V > *View* > *Submitted Changelists*).

The changelists correctly show that there are no files associated with them (because we obliterated them), but the changelist descriptions are still intact and we need those deleted as well (they contain legally "important" information, so we need them gone permanently, period).

Now my question -- is there a way either to:

1) obliterate workspaces and all the changelists pertaining to obliterated depots and workspaces?

2) If not, is there a way to script this so we can clear all descriptions of changelists under the obliterated depots/workspaces? There are thousands of changelists to modify so manual work is impossible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I studied the Helix documentation and came up with a scripted solution. In case anyone has the same problem, I'm posting my steps to solve this below:

0) This requires all of the changelists you want to delete to have all files associated with the changelists to have been obliterated beforehand. If you haven't done that, use `p4 obliterate` to remove the files from the depots.

1) In command prompt with admin rights, run:
`p4 changes -c the-name-of-your-workspace >c:\prune.bat`

2) Open the file c:\prune.bat in a text editor that has regular expressions (regex).

3) Using regex, replace all occurrences of the string "**Change** " with "**p4 change -f -d** "  (without double quotes, of course).

4) Replace all strings matching " **on 2.*$**" with an empty string (removes the remaining portion of the line until its end). Note: The number 2 in the search regex pattern matches the first digit of years 2000-2019 and beyond. If you have changes before the year 2000, use the digit 1.

5) Inspect your batch file, it should contain something like this:

`p4 change -f -d 2083
p4 change -f -d 2074
p4 change -f -d 2073
p4 change -f -d 2072
p4 change -f -d 2071`

6) Run your batch from the command prompt with admin rights.

Enjoy. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy one-line solution that works on any platform:

```
p4 -Ztag -F "change -df %change%" changes -c CLIENT | p4 -x - run
```

If the idea is to get rid of all changelists where the files have been obliterated (i.e. all empty changelists), then you can leave off the `-c CLIENT`.  The `change -df` command will skip changes where the files haven't been obliterated, so it's fine to just run it over all changes.

Comment: Fortunately, as I wrote before you posted this, I have been able to achieve what I wanted. So I won't be able to test your solution. But thank you, anyway.